# multiple identical pointers, can't figure out why

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C, I feel like I'm probably just making a dumb mistake, but I have tried googling this with no luck (maybe I'm just not searching the right things)

Essentially, I tried to write my own object class, and then make several instances of it, but the data seems locked together; Changing the data for any one reference changes it for all of them.

here's where I make the objects and use them.

```
@implementation Drawing
//leaving many functions out as they are not part of the problem

Ball * balls[10];
int numPoints;

//this gets called first
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    //leaving out loading of images.....

    numPoints=10;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        balls[i]=[[Ball alloc] init];
        printf("bmem: %p\n",%balls[i]);
        float tpx=arc4random()%1024;
        float tpy=arc4random()%768;
        printf("randX: %f\n",tpx);
        printf("randY: %f\n",tpy);
        CGPoint tempPt = CGPointMake(tpx,tpy);
        printf("mem: %p\n",%tempPt);
        [balls[i] setLocation:tempPt];
    }
    //code to start a timer on the drawRect function....
}

//called regularly, every 30 seconds
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(c, rect);

    for(int i=0; i<numPoints; i++)
    {
        int ptX=[balls[i] getX];
        int ptY=[balls[i] getY];
        printf("index: %d\n",i);
        printf("x: %d\n",ptX);
        printf("y: %d\n",ptY);
        CGContextDrawImage(c, CGRectMake((int)ptX-WIDTH/2, (int)ptY-WIDTH/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT), image);
    }
}
```

This program outputs a series of numbers which I thought would be useful. 
- "bmem", or the point in memory where the ball is, increments by regular intervals, as expected. 
- "randX" and "randY" are completely random, as they should be.
- "mem", or the point in memory with the CGPoint, doesn't change

and this is the ball object:

```
@implementation Ball
int x;
int y;

-(void)setLocation:(CGPoint)loc{
    x=loc.x;
    y=loc.y;
}

-(int)getX{
    return x;
}

-(int)getY{
    return y;
}

@end
```

At first I just though I had static attributes in the Ball class, but on googling I found out that objective-c does not have static attributes. I've blindly tried about a dozen different things with no success. I really just need this to work.

Comment: You're showing us how you've implemented your class, but not how you're using the functions. Show us some of your function calls, how you're creating the CGPoint you're passing in e.t.c

Comment: @nathanwhite - The problem has been resolved. If you were wondering, the CGPoint was made with the "CGPointMake" function, part of the iOS libraries (not sure if obj-c or iOS). I left out the altering code because it was fairly intensive (dealing with iOS gestures, multi-touch input, fairly ugly) and I didn't want to freak out a possible helper with lines upon lines of extra code. Basically I had code which would move only one point, but they would all move together.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the global variables:

```
Ball * balls[10];
int numPoints;
```

When you probably want instance variables:

```
@interface Balls : NSObject
{
    Ball * balls[10];
    int numPoints;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: If they're just private ivars, you can also do `@implementation Balls { Ball* balls … } …`, although for all I know that might be a bad practice.